# How long for an app to be approved for Amazon AppStore?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

What is the average time it takes for a application to be reviewed by the [Amazon AppStore](https://developer.amazon.com)?

*(small, non-controversial, quality application, popular on the Android Market)*

I know it is variable, so rough figures (3 days? 3 weeks? 3 months?) of minimum/maximum would be extremely helpful, I am just looking for some real-world examples.

Comment: Amazon Store is hopeless. You'll sell more apps standing near a subway station. Stay clear and stick with Google Play. Amazon takes 1+ week to review, and the downloads are going to be in tens (vs. thousands of apps on Google Play)

Comment: My app approved in less than 2 hours! I submitted my app less than two hours ago. Now got approved. Waiting for it to go from approve to live!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Submitted a free app on the day the Appstore launched (3/23). Two weeks later to the day (4/5) it was approved. Figured it would take longer since they'd be saturated right after launch, but 2 weeks doesn't seem that bad. Now just waiting for it to go live.

Comment: Apps don't go live as soon as they are approved?

Comment: It's not instant. About two hours after approval, it transitioned to "Live" (I never got an email about that transition), but it couldn't be found in the appstore. About 6 hours after approval, it was visible.

Comment: wow, two hours is *fast*

Answer (score 3):

I uploaded my first app before the store opened and it took 4 days to get approved and was live when they launched.

Since the store opened I've submitted two more and they are taking longer.  One was approved after a similar delay but has since been stuck in the "Approved" state for about a week and isn't live yet.  The other (submitted first) is took longer to become approved and also isn't live yet.  Not sure why there is such a delay between becoming approved and going live.

[Amazon have said](http://twitter.com/#!/amznappstoredev/status/54639836614754304) that submissions exploded after the store launched and that they are working hard to get through the backlog.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**  Just under 5 days and counting for my paid app, and just under 4 days and counting for my free app.  The waiting continues...

I'll update when approved.

**Edit 2**  Took 10 days for my paid app and still waiting on my free app.

Answer (score 2):

1 week and still waiting. Since the store was opened only 2 weeks ago, they may be very busy with the new apps. It's probably gonna be faster in a few months

Answer (score 2):

Free app took over a month before AppStore opened. Multiple followups did not appear to speak it up.

A link in my app went to Google Market, so had to resubmit. Then took another 1-2 weeks after that.

Answer (score 1):

I posted 2-3 weeks ago and it's still under review.  Not sure if it's related to my billing address being in China.

Updated:  It's approved last week. 1/24/11.  I don't remember the exact submit date.  It's probably about a few weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I must concentrate my advertising effort on the Android Market for a while... Can you please update your answer when you get the result?

Answer (score 0):

My free app got accepted within two days! Billing address in Japan.

Edit: That was long before Amazon AppStore launched, so I guess they had very few requests at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably they are saturated now, since mostly all the developers from Android are uploading their apps from Android Market.