# Current amazon android app store wait times?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

Just curious how long its taking Amazon to review and approve your android apps? Is it still 2 weeks or so, or are they faster now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thread has a note from July of '1-2 weeks' [How long for an app to be approved for Amazon AppStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733754/how-long-for-an-app-to-be-approved-for-amazon-appstore)
This agrees with what I hear.
Oh, and this very relevant question is supposedly off-topic, similarly to [Amazon Android App Market Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744901/amazon-android-app-market-results)

Answer (score 0):

I submitted my Web App and it took only 6 hours to be approved by Amazon App Store.

They also tell me some easy modifications I can make to be available on more device.

Hope this help.